# getting query string php - jquery - #?id=

Tags: php, jquery, string

I am really stuck and was wondering if someone could lend a hand please,

i know how to get a query string, thats not a problem,

however,
I have links that use jquery to fade out the content and load the new content via links,

usage example below - class="link2" is a reference for the jquery to do what it does lol

> <a href="#?id=2" class="link2">click here</a>

in the href i have to have the # first to stop the page from loading if you get what i mean,

now when i try and get the query string id=2 it says none as there is a # first, there is probably a simple fix for this but i must just be missing it,
i have searched and searched but still cant find the answer

----------------------edit------------------------------
this is what i am trying to do,

enter page, 
sql query runs to display all the reports
click a report and the jquery hides "contmain" and shows "contreports" now a new sql query runs to display the report based on the "id"

now usually i can just get this information from the url and clean it up, hovever as i have jquery running i need to have the "#" for the href so the page does not reload and the jquery can run, but now this is stopping me from being able to retrieve the url query,

Interstellar_Coder
he seems to have the right idea, passing it in the background

Comment: "when i try and get the query string id=2" Um, when you do *what*? Show your code!

Comment: Where are you trying to `get` the `id`? Full code please?

Comment: @pixeldesign, for one you shouldn't use #, you should use javascript:void(0), second if you are using jquery, then there really is no need for that anyway (check this out http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/). Just add a click event to that link. As far as getting the correct id, there are few ways to do this, but there is now a data attribute if you want to use that, which is actually posted as an answer. You can also create a hidden element maybe and get the value.

Comment: @Mat thank you for the javascript:void(0), I am looking at the data element now but i just dont know how to use it, as in get the information from (data-query-string="id=2") to use in a sql query,

Comment: @pixeldesign You know you can edit your post right? Don't answer yourself if it's not an answer. The other thing i would suggest. Get your form working without any ajax and without any javascript. Then once you do that, adding in the ajax portion will be easy. It seems you are making this more complicated than it needs to be. Once you get it going without javascript, you can simply get the reference in the link and submit it via ajax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although i don't fully understand what you're doing, i'm guessing it would be better to store your querystring as a `data` attribute.

```
<a href="#" data-id="2" class="link2">click here</a>
```

Then in your jQuery function.

```
$('.link2').click(function(e){
    var queryString = $(this).data('id'); 
    e.preventDefault();   // prevent the default action
});
```

Comment: i think you are on the right track, 
all i need to do is get the "2" for example so i can use it in a sql query, the problem is i am not very good at this javascript/jquery stuff although i am getting a lot better,
your help so far is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

because of the code i thought it best to post here
i think i am getting close,

@Interstellar_Coder - this is what i have so far but it only ever retrieves the first id,

```
$query1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `".TBL_CATCH_REPORTS."`  order by id DESC");
$query2 = mysql_num_rows($query1);

if(mysql_num_rows($query1) != 0) {?>

<table width="880" style="margin:0 auto">
<?PHP while ($output = mysql_fetch_assoc($query1)) { ?>
<tr class="row">
<td width="190px"><input type="button" class="c_report"value="<?PHP echo $output['id']; ?>" />
View Report <img src="images/icons/arrow_right.png" width="16" height="16" /></a></td>
<td width="210px">Submited by <?PHP echo $output['submitby']; ?></td>
<td width="160px"><?PHP echo $output['date']; ?></td>
<td><?PHP echo $output['title']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?PHP } ?>
</table>

<?PHP }else{ echo '.Sorry there are no catch reports yet'; }?>

<div id="contreport"> content here </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".c_report").click(function () {
            $("#contreport").html('Getting Catch Report......');
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: "data=" + $(".c_report").val(),
            url: "reportdata.php",
            success: function(msg){
                $("#contreport").html(msg)
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

my other page "reportdata.php just gets the value and is then used in a sql statement

```
$getreport = '';
    if (isset($_POST['data']) and trim($_POST['data']) != '' ) {
        $getreport = trim($_POST['data']);
    }
```

i am assuming i need some kind of loop going on in the jquery but i am just lost, been stuck on this all day today again lol

this is all i need

id 1 - link

id 2 - link

id 3 - link

id 4 - link

id 5 - link

click on any and the id will be sent to reportdata.php where the id will be used in a sql statement, then the data returned and displayed, 
its truly sending me mad lol